# Как в Angular написать универсальный метод/получения данных из store в NgRx?

Tags: angular2, redux, angular4, angular5, rxjs

Я изучаю **NgRx**. Для изучения решил сделать мультиязычное приложения на **Angular**. 
Функционал приложения:

1. Изменения языка в **store**
2. Загрузка текстов из **API** (сейчас это просто **json** файл)

Store выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Reducer** выглядит так:

```
import { Action } from "rxjs/scheduler/Action";
import { LangAction } from "./lang.actions";
import { LANG_ACTION } from "./lang.namespace";


const initialState = {
 curentLang: 'ua',
 text: {}
}

export function langReducer (state = initialState, action:LangAction) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case LANG_ACTION.LOAD_TEXT:
   state.text = action.payload;
   return state;
  case LANG_ACTION.CHANGE_LANG:
   state.curentLang = action.payload;
   return state;
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

**Actions** выглядит так:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { LANG_ACTION } from './lang.namespace';

export class LoadText implements Action {
 readonly type = LANG_ACTION.LOAD_TEXT
 constructor(public payload) {}
}
export class ChangeLang implements Action {
 readonly type = LANG_ACTION.CHANGE_LANG
 constructor(public payload) {}
}
export type LangAction = LoadText | ChangeLang;
```

В компоненте я беру данные из **store** так:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LangService } from './lang.service';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { AppState } from './redux/app.state';
import { ChangeLang } from './redux/lang/lang.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  lang: string = 'ru';
  langState: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private langService: LangService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.langState =  this.store.select("langsData");
    this.langService.getTextFromApi();
  }

  changeLang() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ChangeLang(this.lang))
  }

}
```

А в шаблоне вывожу так:

```
<p>Curent lang: {{ (langState | async).curentLang }}</p>
```

Но к сожалению такой метод вывода мене не полностью устраивает(

Вопрос: как написать метод/функцию которая будет принимать алиас текстового поля: будет возвращать текст текущего языка по алиасу?
(Таким примером я хочу научиться универсально брать данные и **store**, до этого работал с **Vuex** в **Vue.js** и там есть специальная сущность **`getters`** которая позволяет удобно возвращать данные из **store** )

Comment: Если я правильно понял ты ищещь штуку которая называется selectors, почитай про них поподробнее, чтобы было примерно понятно что искать createFeatureSelector и createSelector методы должны быть тебе полезны. Вот в [этой](https://medium.com/@demyanyuk/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-angular-ngrx-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-1412bc9adf17) статье есть неплохие и простые примеры селекторов. Они будут так же возвращать Observable.

Comment: селекторы не возвращают `Observable`, селекторы синхронные и передаются параметром в оператор `map`

Comment: Увы, с вами не соглашусь. Прочитайте повнимательнее статью на которую я оставил ссылку в моем ответе. Там результат вызова селектора это observable на который подписывается компонент, что вполне логично так как наш стейт постоянно меняется и мы на него подписаны.

Comment: @ИльяИльин, https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/e0ad3c3eee7a2a16c17036139e5d305fb86418e4/modules/store/src/selector.ts#L525